# How to call cookies to detect which api to call?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redis

I need to check if there's a id in the cookies so I know if a user is logged in or not. Is this allowed in the api file?

So instead of checking if cache is available I need to check if react cookies has a cookies called "id" and then run the api. if not, where would I add it?

```
import Redis from 'ioredis'

let redis = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL)

export default async (req, res) => {
   let start = Date.now();
   let cache = await redis.get("cache")
   cache = JSON.parse(cache)
   let result = {}
   if (cache) {
       console.log("loading from cache")
       result.data = cache
       result.type = "redis"
       result.latency = Date.now() - start;
       return res.status(200).json(result)
   } else {
       console.log("loading from api")
       start = Date.now();
       return fetch('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries')
           .then(r => r.json())
           .then(data => {
               data.sort(function (a, b) {
                   return b.todayCases - a.todayCases;
               });
               result.data = data.splice(1, 11)
               result.type = "api"
               result.latency = Date.now() - start;
               redis.set("cache", JSON.stringify(result.data), "EX", 60)
               return res.status(200).json(result)
           })
   }
}
```